# fade in/fade out UISegmentedControl in XIB

Tags: ios, xcode, xib

I have a UISegmentedControl set up in my XIB.  I want it to appear on viewDidLoad and if the user taps the area of the screen it's in, and then to disappear if the user taps it again or to fade out if the user leaves it alone.

In looking around for how to manage this I've found a lot of stuff about fading UIViews, but not as much on fading individual subviews, and little at all on fading elements in the XIB.  I tried to adapt the UIView stuff but failed.

How can I make this work?

**EDIT:**  Okay, I've got the appearance at viewDidLoad and the fade out working.  But when the user taps the area where the UISegmentedControl is (now invisible because alpha=0), nothing happens.  This is the code I'm using:

```
- (IBAction)tapInvisibleSegContr
//This is connected to the UISegmentedControl with the action Touch Up Inside.  Until now, the segmented control has been at alpha=0 since fading after viewDidLoad.
{
    self.segContrAsOutlet.alpha=1.0;
    [self fadeMethodThatWorksInViewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"Yup, tapped.");
}
```

I'm not even getting the NSLog.  I've got the action hooked up to the UISegmentedControl, with the action Touch Up Inside.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is resident in a xib, just put his alpha to 0, do the properly connections: an Outlet and an IBAction for value changed
Then in the `viwDidLoad` right after `[super viewDidLoad]` write:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{self.mySegOutlet.alpha = 1;}];
```

Inside the IBAction right after you code the answer before the last `}` write:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{self.mySegOutlet.alpha = 0;}];
```

This is the easiest method. 
Bye

Comment: Thanks so much!  That helps with the first part of it, the viewDidLoad.  But now I'm having trouble with the tapping-and-it-reappears thing--I've edited the question to include my code.  I'm sure it's an obvious error....

Comment: A hidden UISegmentedControl, or UIControl instance, will never receive touches if it is hidden or with alpha <0.6. You should find another way ;-)

Comment: Hi Joel, that doesn't mean that is not possible, for instance when the segmented disappear you could overlap a view with clear color background and a tap gesture recogniser on it, and remove it when segmented is visible, but I'm wondering how a user could know that is an active part of the screen if it is invisible.

Comment: Okay, I'll try something like this.  (The segmented control will be visible for several seconds upon viewDidLoad and then fade, so I'm figuring it'll give the user the hint that there's something there if s/he wants....

Answer (score 1):

In the xib set your control's alpha to 0.0, then use `UIView` animation methods to animate its alpha to 1.0. For example:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    self.segmentedControl.alpha = 1.0f;
}];
```

EDIT: To your problem with not getting the action called, try attaching it for the value changed control event - I don't think UISegmentedControl sends for touch up inside.

Comment: Thanks so much!  That helps with the first part of it, the viewDidLoad.  But now I'm having trouble with the tapping-and-it-reappears thing--I've edited the question to include my code.  I'm sure it's an obvious error....

Comment: I really appreciate it--but, alas, changing it to Value Changed doesn't seem to make a difference.  It still refuses to appear.  :(

Comment: The log doesn't get called still either?

Comment: Nope.  The log hates me too.  :)  Though it looks like Andrea (below) has an answer for why....

Comment: I saw her comment, there are workarounds though so hopefully you'll get something to meet your requirement.